# Y86 bubble sort program not sorting properly

Tags: assembly, bubble-sort, y86

I am trying to convert a bubble sort program from assembly to Y86. I started with this C code and then converted it to assembly:

```
void bubbleSort2(long arr[], long len) {
    long i;         // inner loop index
    long tmp;       // temp for swapping
    long *arr_curr; // pointer to element in arr
    long *arr_next; // pointer to next element in arr

    while (len > 1) {
        arr_curr = arr; // begin at the start of arr
        i = 0;
        while (i < len-1) {
            arr_next = arr_curr + 1;  // set next pointer
            if (*arr_curr > *arr_next) {
                // Swap the two elements
                // to bubble up the larger value
                tmp = *arr_curr;
                *arr_curr = *arr_next;
                *arr_next = tmp;
            }
            i++;
            arr_curr = arr_next;  // move to the next element 
        }
        len--;
    }
}
```

So far I've come up with the following:

```
# Execution begins at address 0 
    .pos 0 
    irmovq stack, %rsp   # Set up stack pointer  
    call main            # Execute main program
    halt                 # Terminate program 

# Array
    .align 8
arr:
    .quad 0x64
    .quad 0x34
    .quad 0x40
    .quad 0x25
    .quad 0x12
    .quad 0x22
    .quad 0x11
    .quad 0x90
    .quad 0x55
    .quad 0x42

main:
    irmovq arr, %rdi    
    irmovq $10, %rsi
    call bubble
    ret 

# start bubble
bubble:
   irmovq $1, %rax
outer_loop:
   rrmovq %rsi, %r8
   subq %rax, %r8
   irmovq $1, %r9
   irmovq $0, %rcx
inner_loop:
   rrmovq %rdi, %r10
   addq %rcx, %r10
   mrmovq (%r10), %r11
   mrmovq 8(%r10), %r12
   subq %r12, %r11
   jle no_swap
   subq %r11, %r12
   je no_swap
   jg swap
swap:
   mrmovq (%r10), %r11
   mrmovq 8(%r10), %r12
   rmmovq %r11, 8(%r10)
   rmmovq %r12, (%r10)
no_swap:
   irmovq $8, %r13
   addq %r13, %rcx
   subq %rax, %r8
   jg inner_loop
   rrmovq %rdi, %r10
   subq %rax, %r8
   jg outer_loop
   ret
# end bubble
# The stack starts here and grows to lower addresses
    .pos 0x200      
stack:
```

I keep getting this:

```
Changes to memory:
0x0018: 0x0000000000000064  0x0000000000000034
0x0020: 0x0000000000000034  0x0000000000000040
0x0028: 0x0000000000000040  0x0000000000000025
0x0030: 0x0000000000000025  0x0000000000000012
0x0038: 0x0000000000000012  0x0000000000000022
0x0040: 0x0000000000000022  0x0000000000000011
0x0048: 0x0000000000000011  0x0000000000000064
0x0050: 0x0000000000000090  0x0000000000000055
0x0058: 0x0000000000000055  0x0000000000000042
0x0060: 0x0000000000000042  0x0000000000000090
0x01f0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000085
0x01f8: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000013
```

When I try with less than 5 elements, it's sorted but when i do 10, it's never sorted. Why does that happen? What is the problem with what I wrote, and how can it be corrected?

Comment: Not that this is an issue here, but you have (presumably) working C code, and you've made several small algorithmic changes during assembly translation, for example, counting `i` down instead of up, using `do {} while` instead of `while`, eliminating `arr_next`. These things can easily result in off by one errors, for one, or control flow issues for another.  Best practice is to finish all the algorithmic changes you want in the C version, verify they work, then take working C to assembly literally, i.e. without further algorithmic changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> subq %r12, %r11
> jle no_swap
> subq %r11, %r12
> je no_swap
> jg swap
> ```

I get it that you are using a subtraction to replace a comparison, but what I don't get is the reason for that second subtraction.
Without the second subtraction, there would also be no reason to reload `%r12` (using `cmpq` you wouldn't need to reload either!):

```
   subq   %r12, %r11
   jle    no_swap
swap:
   mrmovq (%r10), %r11
   rmmovq %r11, 8(%r10)
   rmmovq %r12, (%r10)
no_swap:
```

### Outer loop runs only once

> ```
> subq %rax, %r8
> jg inner_loop
> rrmovq %rdi, %r10
> subq %rax, %r8
> jg outer_loop
> ```

The inner loop ends on `%r8` becoming **0**. The `subq %rax, %r8` that follows will leave `%r8` at **-1** and so `jg outer_loop` will stop there and then.
What could make sense is that you decrement the number of elements in the array (contained in `%rsi`):

```
subq %rax, %rsi    # 10 -> 9 -> 8 ... 3 -> 2
cmpq %rax, %rsi
jne  outer_loop
```